# How to run sudo lnav and with user defined formats?

Tags: logging, lnav

I have installed lnav as snap package according to these instructions: http://lnav.org/downloads/

```
sudo snap install lnav
```

I have made couple of proprietary log file formats for inhouse developed program logs. I installed these using commands like:

```
lnav -i bbckpLog.json
info: installed: /home/jk/snap/lnav/116/.lnav/formats/installed/bbckpLog.json
```

and checked that they are correct by using

```
lnav -C
```

They work fine when I e.g. run (proprietary logs are in /home/jk/tmp):

```
lnav /home/jk/tmp /var/log
```

I can browse combined log view with system logs and proprietary logs.

Problem is that when I try to browse those logs only the root user can read (permission 600), sudo lnav cannot find my proprietary formats.

```
sudo lnav /home/jk/tmp /var/log/pm-suspend.log
```

I also tried to give the configuration directory from command line like this:

```
sudo lnav -I /home/jk/snap/lnav/116/.lnav /home/jk/tmp /var/log
```

but it still does not find/use my proprietary formats.

OS is Ubuntu 16.04

How to fix this?